# Как в гугл таблице сопоставить данные из 2-х вкладок по ID?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть [таблица](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hddaoHg324cs7rOgNDl9q4Gsd5K2PfR4RPNZZmrf7gU/edit#gid=0), в которой две вкладки: "Выгрузка1" и "Выгрузка2". В "Выгрузка1" есть данные с ID, в "Выгрузка2" также список данных с ID.

Нужно во вкладку "Выгрузка1" добавить данные из "Выгрузка2" в соответствующую по ID строчку.

Подскажите, плиз, решение...

P.S.  В первой вкладке данных может быть больше

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам будет достаточно использования формулы

```
={"";
  ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
    A2:A100;
    'Выгрузка 2'!A:B;2;
  );""))
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причины для создания скрипта пока не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

Справится простая формула с `ВПР`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;'Выгрузка 2'!$A$2:$B$8;2;0);"")
```

Можно и в локали записать:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ВПР(A2;'Выгрузка 2'!$A$2:$B$8;2;0);"")
```

Вариант с `ИНДЕКС/ПОИСКПОЗ` (`INDEX/MATCH`) и с проверкой наличия `ID` в списке:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Выгрузка 2'!$A$2:$A$8;A2);INDEX('Выгрузка 2'!$B$2:$B$8;MATCH(A2;'Выгрузка 2'!$A$2:$A$8;0));"")
```