# Сопоставить данные из двух вкладок Google таблицы по ID?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Есть таблица https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zcSZnJAFT7mysG11e4iWkkKZegvxeDNHsijlrJGvWcU/edit#gid=0, в которой две вкладки: "Сделки" и "Контакты". Во вкладке "Сделки" есть данные с ID (Столбец А), в "Контакты" также список данных с ID. (ID Сделок) Столбец F.

Нужно во вкладку "Сделки" добавить данные из "Контакты" (имя - столбец B / и телефон столбец R) в соответствующую по ID строчку. (Столбцы BA, BB)

Подскажите, плиз, решение...

P.S. В первой вкладке данных может быть больше

Comment: Наверное, вам стоит проверить свои прошлые вопросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324067/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%87, а то как-то не очень.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1242099/Как-в-гугл-таблице-сопоставить-данные-из-2-х-вкладок-по-id - Дубль вопроса

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в гугл таблице сопоставить данные из 2-х вкладок по ID?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1242099/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-2-%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-id)